# horizontal line does not look right. What is the reason?

Tags: html, css

I am putting horizontal line after each li. What I want to do is hr should be in the same distance to li(s).

This is my css to put hr

```
.divider {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background:  #ccc;
}
```

This one of the li(s)

```
<li style="width:210px;padding:10px 0 10px 0" class="memberElement">
  <div class="MemberImageHolder" style="float:left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="mediumMemberPicture" src="picture.php?action=display&amp;contentType=members&amp;id=20&amp;quality=medium" alt="" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="memberDetails" style="float:right">
    <a href="#">Mert Metin<br></a>
    <span id="title">
      Administrator<br><br>
    </span>
    <span id="unit">
      <b>University of Ottawa</b>
      <br>
    </span>
  </div>
  <span class="divider"></span>
</li>
```

However, this is how it looks:

[image]

Why it looks like that?

Comment: What is your HTML markup?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you're not just applying a `border-bottom` to the `li`, but hey, to each their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing your floats before the `<span class="divider">` element. Since sibling `<div>` elements are floated, you'll need to clear the float before placing an element below them.

See also: [clearfix](http://www.adamkaplan.me/css-clearfix/)

Also, CSS [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) applies to `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements. I have removed it as it is not useful here.

```css
.divider {
    ...
    clear: both;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.divider {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="width:210px;padding:10px 0 10px 0" class="memberElement">
    <div class="MemberImageHolder" style="float:left">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="mediumMemberPicture" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
      </a>

    </div>
    <div class="memberDetails" style="float:right"><a href="#">Mert Metin<br></a><span id="title">Administrator<br><br></span><span id="unit"><b>University of Ottawa</b><br></span>

    </div><span class="divider"></span>

  </li>
  <li style="width:210px;padding:10px 0 10px 0" class="memberElement">
    <div class="MemberImageHolder" style="float:left">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="mediumMemberPicture" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
      </a>

    </div>
    <div class="memberDetails" style="float:right"><a href="#">Mert Metin<br></a><span id="title">Administrator<br><br></span><span id="unit"><b>University of Ottawa</b><br></span>

    </div><span class="divider"></span>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add `after`:

```
.divider:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background:  #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Why not using this on li?

Comment: @MertMetin There is no `<hr>` in your code. That class is applied to a `<span>`.

Comment: so should put hr instead?